# EF Core Doesn't Load The Entity That Has Been Added To DB Through SqlRaw

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I've used `EF Core` with [SQLite DataBase Provider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite). When I try to find the entity that has been added to DB through a SqlRaw command, the `First()` method returns null, while I expect it shouldn't be. And I want to know why?

But:

- If I use `int` as key for the model class, there is no problem.
- If I add the entity via `DbContext`, everything would work as I expect.

Test class:

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        var connectionStringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder()
        {
            DataSource = ":memory:",
        };
        var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
            options
            .UseSqlite(connection));
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var context = serviceProvider.GetService<MyDbContext>();
        context.Database.OpenConnection();
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();


        var id = Guid.NewGuid();
        AddDevice(context, id);


        Assert.NotEmpty(context.Devices); // OK
        Assert.NotNull(context.Devices.First(x => x.Id == new DeviceId(id)); // Fail
    }

    private void AddDevice(MyDbContext context, Guid id)
    {
        string sqlInsert = $"INSERT INTO \"Devices\" (\"Id\") VALUES ('{id}')";
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sqlInsert);
    }
```

the Model class:

```
public class Device
{
    public DeviceId Id { get; private set; }
    private string _token; 
    
    private Device()
    {
    }

    public Device(string token)
        : this()
    {
        Id = new DeviceId(Guid.NewGuid());
        _token = token;
    }
}

public class DeviceId : IEquatable<DeviceId>
{
    public Guid Value { get; }

    public DeviceId(Guid guid)
    {
        this.Value = guid;
    }

    public bool Equals(DeviceId other)
    {
        return this.Value.Equals(other.Value);
    }
}
```

the Configuration class:

```
internal class DeviceConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Device>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Device> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Devices");

        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasConversion(
                v => v.Value,
                v => new DeviceId(v));

        builder.Property<string>("_token").HasColumnName("Token");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you over-complicating a GUID ID with a class? And why not just create an entity and add it to the DbContext rather than raw SQL?  This may just be an example scenario, but start with the simplest thing. What justifies the extra complexity/deviation from letting EF manage things the way it was designed?